# Insert Non media (pdf, txt ,doc) android

Tags: android

my application will downloads non media files like PDF,TXT, XML etc. Using following code I am saving in storage.

```
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Save locaation");

                    final int fileBufferSizee = 1024;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileBufferSizee ];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }

                    in.close();
                    in = null;
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    out = null;
```

working fine. Actually I need URI of saved file. for that I need to insert information in android media database.

How to insert non media files in android media database ? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want to get URL from absolute path  then do this

```
 Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg").toString()));
```

save this in one URI variable

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sharma, But how to insert information in android media database ?

Comment: what to want to save like file path , media file bitmap etc etc is it u want dude

Comment: like this  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, attachmentSavePath);
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
      attachmentSaveUri = this.getContentResolver().insert(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

Comment: then make one wrapper class and save all values inside that wrapper class :)